# JQuery wrap the whole part after clone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

See jsfiddle first

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/helisz/u3Ttc/)

I have to convert the source structure

```
<div class="out">
 <a>im here</a>
 <a>to save</a>
 <a>our</a>
 <a>country</a>
</div>
```

into

```
<div class="newout">
    <ul>
        <li class="haha">
            <a>im here</a>
            <span><a>im here</a></span>
        </li>
        <li class="haha">
            <a>to save</a>
            <span><a>to save</a></span>
        </li>
        <li class="haha">
            <a>our</a>
            <span><a>our</a></span>
        </li>
        <li class="haha">
            <a>country</a>
            <span><a>country</a></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

That means I have to do the following procedures:

- 1.clone `a` tag
- 2.wrap it with `span` tag
- 3.append it to previous `a` tag
- 4.wrap previous tags in to `li` tag, and add class
- 5.then wrap all previous elements into `ul` tag

I don't know how to use JQuery to implement STEP4. I have no idea about how to get these tags and add a wrap.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: another way of doing this http://jsfiddle.net/u3Ttc/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $ct = $('.out').removeClass('out').addClass('newout');
    var $ul = $('<ul />').appendTo($ct);
    $ct.children('a').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.wrap('<li class="haha" />');
        $('<span />').append($this.clone()).insertAfter($this);
        $this.parent().appendTo($ul)
    })

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Du7Rv/)

Or

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    var $ct = $('.out').removeClass('out').addClass('newout');
    var $ul = $('<ul />').appendTo($ct);
    $ct.children('a').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $('<li />', {
            'class': 'haha'
        }).append(this).append($('<span />').append($this.clone())).appendTo($ul)
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fbggH/)